How make pagination work with re-order of collection.products (first available product then out of stock) Shopify Liquid
I'm using a code to re-order the products in a collection, I separated the products in stock and the products out of stock into two arrays, then I concatenated them and used this object to render card_product, so far so good, but when the collection does pagination what happens is that each page first show in stock product and then those out of stock.
As I said code work for each page:
Page 1: first in stock then out of stock
Page 2: first in stock then out of stock
etc...
I would like to make all in stock first and in the last pages the out of stock products.
Theme used is Dawn by Shopify
{% assign available_products = collection.products | where: 'available' %}
{% assign out_of_stock_products = collection.products | where: 'available', false %}
{% assign products = available_products | concat: out_of_stock_products %}
{%- for product in products -%}
{% assign lazy_load = false %}
{%- if forloop.index > 2 -%}
{%- assign lazy_load = true -%}
{%- endif -%}
<li class="grid__item">
{% render 'card-product',
card_product: product,
media_aspect_ratio: section.settings.image_ratio,
show_secondary_image: section.settings.show_secondary_image,
show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
show_rating: section.settings.show_rating,
lazy_load: lazy_load,
show_quick_add: section.settings.enable_quick_add,
section_id: section.id
%}
</li>
{%- endfor -%}

